# How can I get the commands for all of the parents of a particular process with just the ps command?

Tags: bash, process

I'm familiar with how to use these commands:

```
$ sudo ps -ef f
$ pstree
```

But they print the tree for every process.

I want just a list of the commands/arguments used for all the parents of the **current process** but only using the `ps` command.

And I want the list in the correct hierarchial order.

So, for example, if my process tree looks like:

```
root        6334       1  0 15:48 ?        Sl     0:01 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace moby -id 4b8ff8e11a38cf3c7ec6d8259014f494c5e8628306ae16906826d867324e4afc -address /run/containerd/containerd.
root        6393    6334  0 15:48 ?        Ss     0:00  \_ /package/admin/s6/command/s6-svscan -d4 -- /run/service
root        6929    6393  0 15:48 ?        S      0:00      \_ s6-supervise s6-linux-init-shutdownd
root        6940    6929  0 15:48 ?        Ss     0:00      |   \_ /package/admin/s6-linux-init/command/s6-linux-init-shutdownd -c /run/s6/basedir -g 3000 -C -B
root        7256    6393  0 15:48 ?        S      0:00      \_ s6-supervise s6rc-oneshot-runner
root        7288    7256  0 15:48 ?        Ss     0:00      |   \_ /package/admin/s6/command/s6-ipcserverd -1 -- /package/admin/s6/command/s6-ipcserver-access -v0 -E -l0 -i data/rules -- /package/admin/s6/comm
root        7257    6393  0 15:48 ?        S      0:00      \_ s6-supervise s6rc-fdholder
root        7258    6393  0 15:48 ?        S      0:00      \_ s6-supervise svc-bazarr
nacho       7578    7258  0 15:48 ?        Ss     0:00          \_ python3 /app/bazarr/bin/bazarr.py --no-update --config /config
nacho       7825    7578  0 15:48 ?        Sl     0:33              \_ /usr/bin/python3 -u /app/bazarr/bin/bazarr/main.py --no-update --config /config
root        6373       1  0 15:48 ?        Sl     0:01 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace moby -id a67ced46f899d8359864da27ff51aae53d32d3d68fd1383fbcf64ca4bcf523ba -address /run/containerd/containerd.
root        6401    6373  0 15:48 ?        Ss     0:00  \_ /package/admin/s6/command/s6-svscan -d4 -- /run/service
root        6623    6401  0 15:48 ?        S      0:00      \_ s6-supervise s6-linux-init-shutdownd
root        6626    6623  0 15:48 ?        Ss     0:00      |   \_ /package/admin/s6-linux-init/command/s6-linux-init-shutdownd -c /run/s6/basedir -g 3000 -C -B
root        6733    6401  0 15:48 ?        S      0:00      \_ s6-supervise s6rc-oneshot-runner
root        6769    6733  0 15:48 ?        Ss     0:00      |   \_ /package/admin/s6/command/s6-ipcserverd -1 -- /package/admin/s6/command/s6-ipcserver-access -v0 -E -l0 -i data/rules -- /package/admin/s6/comm
root        6734    6401  0 15:48 ?        S      0:00      \_ s6-supervise s6rc-fdholder
root        6735    6401  0 15:48 ?        S      0:00      \_ s6-supervise svc-de
nacho       7107    6735  0 15:48 ?        Ss     0:00      |   \_ /bin/bash /defaults/startwm.sh
nacho       7142    7107  0 15:48 ?        S      0:00      |       \_ /usr/bin/openbox --startup /usr/libexec/openbox-autostart OPENBOX
nacho       7826    7142  0 15:48 ?        S      0:00      |           \_ /bin/sh /usr/libexec/openbox-autostart OPENBOX
nacho       7831    7826  0 15:48 ?        S      0:00      |               \_ sh /config/.config/openbox/autostart
nacho       7832    7831  0 15:48 ?        Sl     0:52      |                   \_ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
nacho       8043    7832  0 15:48 ?        Sl     0:00      |                       \_ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -parentBuildID 20230802111331 -prefsLen 28349 -prefMapSize 232511 -appDir /usr/lib/f
nacho       8092    7832  0 15:48 ?        Sl     0:01      |                       \_ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 1 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 28425 -prefMapSize 232511 -jsInitLen 242676 -pare
nacho       8179    7832  0 15:48 ?        Sl     0:00      |                       \_ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 32965 -prefMapSize 232511 -jsInitLen 242676 -pare
nacho       8215    7832  0 15:48 ?        Sl     0:00      |                       \_ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 3 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 29163 -prefMapSize 232511 -jsInitLen 242676 -pare
nacho       8241    7832  0 15:48 ?        Sl     0:00      |                       \_ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 4 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 29163 -prefMapSize 232511 -jsInitLen 242676 -pare
nacho       8245    7832  0 15:48 ?        Sl     0:00      |                       \_ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 5 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 291
```

And the current processes PID is `8179`, then I want this output:

```
/usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace moby -id a67ced46f899d8359864da27ff51aae53d32d3d68fd1383fbcf64ca4bcf523ba -address /run/containerd/containerd.
/package/admin/s6/command/s6-svscan -d4 -- /run/service
s6-supervise svc-de
/bin/bash /defaults/startwm.sh
/usr/bin/openbox --startup /usr/libexec/openbox-autostart OPENBOX
/bin/sh /usr/libexec/openbox-autostart OPENBOX
sh /config/.config/openbox/autostart
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 32965 -prefMapSize 232511 -jsInitLen 242676 -pare
```

Comment: You may want to take a closer look at the `pstree` man page, because it does not just "print the tree for every process". In particular, see the `-s` option.

Comment: Understood. But I can't use the `pstree` command. I need to use just `ps`. The target system only has `ps` installed and `pstree` is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of `ps` having options to show ancestors, rather it has only options to show immediate parent(PPID).

pstree might do the trick with sed, you may choose to other text processors if sed is unavailable.

```
$ pstree -s 98818 -a |sed 's/^.*`-//g'
systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 22
httpd -DFOREGROUND
httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

Comment: I can't use the `pstree` command. I need to use just `ps`. The target system only has `ps` installed and `pstree` is not available.

Answer (score 0):

`ps` by itself can't show ancestors like that, but you can wrap it in a simple shell script; something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

target=$1
tree=()

while :; do
    echo "[$target] $(ps -p $target -o args --no-headers)"
    (( target == 1 )) && break

    ppid=$(ps -p $target -o ppid --no-headers)
    tree+=($ppid)
    target=$ppid
done
```

Which gives me, for example:

```
$ sh showparents.sh $$
[1784467] -bash
[  11399] tmux
[   9470] /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user
[      1] /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize=35
```

This "only uses the  `ps` command" by one reading, since everything else here is a shell builtin (no dependencies on awk/sed/grep/etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
getPidParents(){
  awk -v pid="$1" '
    $2 == pid {
        child=pid
        pid=parent=$3
        for (i=1;i<=7;i++) $i=""
        sub(/^ */,"")
        printf "[PID: %8d] [PPID: %8d] %s\n", child, parent, $0
    }
  ' <(tac <(ps -ef)) | tac
}

getPidParents 1085

[PID:        1] [PPID:        0] /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 17
[PID:     1036] [PPID:        1] /usr/sbin/sssd -i --logger=files
[PID:     1085] [PPID:     1036] /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_ssh --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
```

Example: fake.sh  pid=1757793

```
ps -ef f

...
root        1229       1  0 Aug02 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D -oCiphers=aes256-gcm@openssh.com, ...
root     1754512    1229  0 12:18 ?        Ss     0:00  \_ sshd: ufopilot [priv]
ufopilot  1754519 1754512  0 12:18 ?        S      0:00  |   \_ sshd: ufopilot@pts/0
ufopilot  1754521 1754519  0 12:18 pts/0    Ss     0:00  |       \_ -bash
root     1754584 1754521  0 12:18 pts/0    S      0:00  |           \_ sudo -iu user
user   1754586 1754584  0 12:18 pts/0    S      0:00  |               \_ -bash
user   1757549 1754586  0 12:43 pts/0    S      0:00  |                   \_ bash
user   1757550 1757549  0 12:43 pts/0    S      0:00  |                       \_ bash
user   1757551 1757550  0 12:43 pts/0    S      0:00  |                           \_ bash
user   1757552 1757551  0 12:43 pts/0    S      0:00  |                               \_ bash
user   1757553 1757552  0 12:43 pts/0    S      0:00  |                                   \_ bash
user   1757583 1757553  0 12:43 pts/0    S      0:00  |                                       \_ bash
user   1757584 1757583  0 12:43 pts/0    S      0:00  |                                           \_ bash
user   1757585 1757584  0 12:43 pts/0    S      0:00  |                                               \_ bash
user   1757586 1757585  0 12:43 pts/0    S      0:00  |                                                   \_ bash
user   1757793 1757586  0 12:45 pts/0    S+     0:00  |                                                       \_ /bin/bash ./fake.sh
...

getPidParents 1757793
[PID:        1] [PPID:        0] /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 17
[PID:     1229] [PPID:        1] /usr/sbin/sshd -D -oCiphers=aes256-gcm@openssh ...
[PID:  1754512] [PPID:     1229] sshd: ufopilot [priv]
[PID:  1754519] [PPID:  1754512] sshd: ufopilot@pts/0
[PID:  1754521] [PPID:  1754519] -bash
[PID:  1754584] [PPID:  1754521] sudo -iu user
[PID:  1754586] [PPID:  1754584] -bash
[PID:  1757549] [PPID:  1754586] bash
[PID:  1757550] [PPID:  1757549] bash
[PID:  1757551] [PPID:  1757550] bash
[PID:  1757552] [PPID:  1757551] bash
[PID:  1757553] [PPID:  1757552] bash
[PID:  1757583] [PPID:  1757553] bash
[PID:  1757584] [PPID:  1757583] bash
[PID:  1757585] [PPID:  1757584] bash
[PID:  1757586] [PPID:  1757585] bash
[PID:  1757793] [PPID:  1757586] /bin/bash ./fake.sh
```